# How to add ansi null and ansi warning in connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using RDO Connection

Connection String

```
Set RdoVisPay = rdoVISENV.OpenConnection("VISA", 1, False, "DSN=VISA;UID=sa;PWD=sa;APP=Visual Basic;WSID=" & ServerName & ";DATABASE=" & Database1)
```

Showing error as "heterogeneous queries require the ansi_nulls and ansi_warnings options to be set for the connection"

How to add the ansi_nulls and ansi_warning Connection in the connection string.

Need Suggestion and Help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. They are set per connection, but not in the connection string. So run some SQL after creating the connections

```
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
```

Note though, the error you have is caused by a linked server call from your SQL Server. Depending on how you set this up (say via a stored procedure) you may need to change the stored proc or view, or set the values in the code. Hard to say as it stands.

Comment: How can i add this line in insert query...?

Comment: @user1157846; no idea. Not enough information

Answer (score 1):

This is a confirmed bug of sql2000.

Check the info about it [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296769/en-us).

Comment: Link is now broken